# How to configure WFS layer with OpenLayers in PHP WampServer?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, php, proxy

I have a problem to display WFS layer outside the GeoServer. My code working fine in GeoServer, but when I tried my code in WampServer(PHP), only WMS layer is being to displayed.

I've gone through many tutorial and stack overflow queries related to adding WFS layer in OpenLayers but nothing working in my case... I have also tried proxy.cgi scripts to allow proxy call to GeoServer, but it not works. Is CGI proxy script can be used only with Python or it can be used with PHP as well?

Comment: have you tried using a PHP proxy file?

Comment: could you please help me :
I want to show postgres query output in openlayer using php.?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 1):

You need a PHP proxy.
This is a simple proxy.php script. It will be completely open, and you might want to lock it down.

```
<?php
 $ch = curl_init($_GET['url']);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 $output = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $output;
?>
```

In your OpenLayers JavaScript config point to you proxy.php script with the following:

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "proxy.php?url=";
```

Source: http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/proxy-and-apache-tp3912603p3912617.html

Comment: Thanks for replay Devdatta Tengshe!!
I have tried this but its not working. Do I have to make some changes in conf file or some any other file.

Comment: What do you mean when you say it is not working? Are you getting any errors in Firebug?

Comment: Firebug not showing any error only WMS layer is being displayed means WFS layer is still missing.

Comment: If firebug's console is not showing any error that means the problem is somewhere else. Is the request atleast being sent? (See in the net tab of firebug)