# OpenLayers 6 TileWMS over server-side proxy script

Tags: openlayers, proxy

Let's say I've simple PHP proxy script:

```
$ch = curl_init($_GET['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

How do I have to change TileWMS that the full URL with get vars will be parsed to my proxy?

```
  new TileLayer({
    source: new TileWMS({
    // not working I would look for a way to pass the ready URL with get vars here
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/proxy.php?url=https://some.server/geoserver/xyz/wms',
    params: {'LAYERS': 'basic:tigers', 'TILED': false},
    serverType: 'geoserver'
    })
  })
```

It looks in former versions of `OL OpenLayers.ProxyHost` [existed](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56829/how-to-configure-wfs-layer-with-openlayers-in-php-wampserver) . The reason is to hide some basic auth header.

Comment: what is the problem with that solution?, what is the error you are getting?

Comment: @cabesuon look at the proxy, I would need to pass the full url with get vars from openlayers to (`https://some.server/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=`)